# Issue with upgrading TFS Checkin Policies to VS2015

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I have two policies that works with VS2013. I wanted to make those policies work with VS2015, but can't find the TFS API libraries for VS2015.
I tried adding this

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll"

as a reference to my Policy projects and it compiled fine. When I try to register them, one of them worked, other one didn't. I get the exception below:

> Internal error in [MyPolicy]. Error loading the [MyPolicy] policy (The
>   policy assembly 'MyPolicy, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' is not registered.). Installation instructions:
>   Please see the web based installation instructions.

Why the first policy got regsitered fine, but not the second one? Someone know the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've tried referencing a VS2013 assembly (v12.0).
You need to reference VS2015 assemblies (v14.0) at `"%CommonProgramFiles%\microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\14.0"`

Comment: what assemblies are needed for that? In our architecture we have created something similar to GAC, and we need to reference it from there, rather than Microsoft's path. But again when we reference it from there, it says that it can't find the correct version.