# Checkin Policy not working after upgrading to VS 2015 and tfpt2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

this one was asked but not answered properly.
We are running VS2015, along with **tfs2013** for source control. We have a checkin policy that enforces a checkin Comment and for the user to assign a Work Item(s) to the checkin. This has been working fine as expected for a while.
we just upgrade to use tfpt 2015 and we get this message while doing checkin from the explorer menu:

> Internal error in Work Items. Error loading the Work Items policy (The
>   policy assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
>   not registered.).

Installation instructions:

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203112/internal-error-in-changeset-comments-policy-after-updating-vs2015-to-update-1) ? or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716474/issue-with-upgrading-tfs-checkin-policies-to-vs2015?rq=1) ?